# How to remove fluid source mid animation

Tags: objects, fluid-simulation

I'm very new to blender, following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=viiOpt0JhfU&) tutorial I made an identical animation but I'd like to have a few frames where no more fluid is added but all that had already been poured will keep being simulated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Select your inflow object.
2. In physics properties hit I while hovering with the mouse over the "Use Flow" checkbox.
3. Move one frame forward in your timeline.
4. Uncheck the "Use Flow" checkbox
5. Repeat step 2

Done.

[image]